# Crystal report not found in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

PLease guide me, what should i install to create ASP.NET - crystal report in visual studio 2012 ?

Comment: Installed? http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-visual-studio/index.html

Comment: it is not free.please share some free solution to create crystal report in vs2012 - ASP.NET.

Comment: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3303855

Answer (score 1):

Use this url:

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_5.exe

You can try to change the version of the url, like:

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_6.exe
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_7.exe

EDIT: Or you can use this link:

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824